# GCP SQL instance is stuck on restart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

My GCP SQL instance is stuck on restart. Is there way to force stop or restart or to access the database backups so I can create a new one from the backup?

Answer (score 0):

After 1 hour the instance restart failed due to an unknown error.

The original instance was `db-n1-standard-1`. I created a new instance type `db-n1-standard-2` (more memory and 2CPU) and I managed to restore a backup to the new instance. 
Any other operations to restore backup or clone in the `db-n1-standard-1` failed.